# Use a Span Class with @HTML Raw Links

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```
 string tag = "<td> <a href="+ path + ">" + "<span class=glyphicon glyphicon-trash" + ">" + "</span>" + "</a>" + "</td>";
 }
 @Html.Raw(tag)
```

Nothing appears when I tried to use the glyphicon icon. Am i missing any syntax to use the span class in this instance?

Comment: Do you have `@{` at the beginning of that code block?

Comment: yes i do. It does work when im just using plain text as the link value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the class value and href value in quotes too, as far as I know.:

```
 string tag = "<td> <a href='" + path + "'>" + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'" + ">" + "</span>" + "</a>" + "</td>";
```